# URL Scheme for Android

Tags: android, cordova, url-scheme

At the moment I create a shortcut app with PhoneGap which opens Whatsapp, Youtube, etc. just with a click on the button. For iOS I can use the normal URL Scheme `<a href="whatsapp://">CLICK</a>` in order to open WhatsApp from my App. Is there something similar for Android as there exist no URL schemes?

Answer (score 2):

I found a good plugin in order to use something simliar as the URL schemes.

[StartApp](https://github.com/lampaa/org.apache.cordova.startapp)

After installing the plugin you just have to use the Play Store Name of the App, for example for Facebook you can use `com.facebook.katana` as shown in the last part of the Play Store URL of the app.