# Open Whatsapp using Custom URL Scheme from Android Phonegap

Tags: cordova, whatsapp, custom-url

I have tried to open Whatsapp from Android Phonegap but getting application error:

```
"The protocol is not supported. (whatsapp://send?text=Hi)"
```

Tested on Andriod phones 2.3 and 4.4. But same error is shown

Javascript:

```
document.location.href = 'whatsapp://send?text=Hi';
```

Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I see your problem.

Try: `<a href="whatsapp://">CLICK</a>`

If that has no effect, you can refer to [this](https://github.com/lampaa/org.apache.cordova.startapp) plugin.

Another stackoverflow question similar to yours: [URL Scheme for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26203743/url-scheme-for-android)